# Improving UIWebview loading performances

Tags: iphone, performance, image, uiwebview, frame

In my iPhone app, I'm using a UIwebview to execute javascript only. The webview is always hidden, no interaction required. I'm searching for tips to improve load time so my app can become more responsive.
From your experience :

- Setting a webview frame at 1x1 pix could improve the performances ?
  I assume here image rendering and other UI stuff could be ignored ?
- Setting alpha to 0 could improve the performances ?
  I assume here image rendering and other UI stuff could be ignored ?
- Disabling "scales page to fit", link, phone detections could improve performances ?
- Preventing images and CSS loading could help, but I still not know how this could be done.

Any tips greatly appreciated
Thanks !
J

Answer (score 0):

For preventing images loading in the webview, I used this http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html

I substitute all larges images in the webview by a 1 pix image stored in the local bundle. 
And it just works fine !